# How to get the row of the updated cell in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want the row and column of a cell that is updated and whose column is "H". I tried the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox Target.Row
End If

End Sub
```

When I just click a cell it gives me correct row but when I edit a cell and press enter, Message shows output as the next row and not the row of the edited cell.

How can I get row/column of the edited cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Worksheet_Change, not Worksheet_SelectionChange.

Worksheet_SelectionChange is triggered when you select a different cell or range of cells.

Worksheet_Change is triggered when one or more cells' values change from typing, pasting or VBA. A change in the calculated value from a formula does not trigger it. For a calculation change, use Worksheet_Calculate.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Target(1).Row
    End If

End Sub
```

It is very possible that Target could be more than a single cell; hence Target(1).Row to get the first cell in Target.